# Excel functions showing wrong results

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have got a strange problem.
I'm using Office 2007. In Excel, I type the formula

```
=T.INV(0,975;99)
```

It is giving me 0,013417295 as a result. However, this should be 1,984. What could be wrong?

Comment: In my region I need to use a different syntax, i.e. =T.INV(0.975,99)....but I get 1.984

Comment: The `T.INV` function is the _left-tailed inverse_ of the Student's t-distribution.  The `T.INV.2T` function is the _two-tailed inverse_ of the Student's t-distribution – and so is the `TINV` function. Are you sure that you aren’t calling `TINV`?

Comment: I'm sure I inserted correct formula, according to the regional settings. If  I insert =T.INV(0.975,99) it will give a syntax error

Comment: I second Barry's result. I also get 1.984.

Comment: This doesn’t make any sense. How can `=T.INV(anything)` return any result in Excel 2007 ***when T.INV didn’t exist in Excel before 2010***? BTW, I get 0.031417295 for `=TINV(0.975, 99)`.

Comment: I can assure you that I use the 2007 version and the T.INV function is there...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using 0.975 as a whole. I guess you want a 95% confindence interval, then you should use 0.025 (2.5% in each tail)

The absolute value of that answer is exactly the one you were looking for :)
Hope it helps!!!